# Proper grounding of a half open measurement bridge with zeroing variable resistor

Tags: grounding, measurement, texas-instruments, wheatstone-bridge

I am designing a circuit to read a differential pressure sensor.

The manufacturer gives the following diagram of the half-open measurement bridge:

[image: Circuit diagram]

My understanding is that I am designing a circuit to accurately measure the voltage difference between -OUT and +OUT. I am providing a constant current of 1 mA to +IN. My question is specifically about the -IN side of this circuit. Do I just need to ground one side of the variable resistor?

If so should I ground this to the analog ground reference pin on the IC? For reference, [I am using this IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads122c04.pdf?ts=1636478297397&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fstore%252Fti%252Fen%252Fp%252Fproduct%252F%253Fp%253DADS122C04IPW) and the following circuit as my baseline. The only difference is that I am using AIN0 as a constant current source given the built-in features to do that.

[image: IC circuit]

Comment: The wiper of R5 becomes ‘ground’. You probably don’t need the 1mA current source - just run on 5V and use ratiometric.  You could omit R3.4.5 and zero the reading programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this clears things up @Kartman . In theory, the sensor will come calibration sheet that will give the R3,4. 

Aah okay, so using the wiper as ground basically allows you to add resistance to either side of the circuit as you change the resistance. 

You are probably right about using 5V but the components are rated to a max of 3mA. So I think it would still depend on the total bridge resistance if that is doable or not. I see the advantage is that I could run more sensors off of the chip.

Would going full ratiometric increase the noise in the system? Cheers.

Comment: Even with the current source you’d be using ratiometric methinks. with the current source the excitation would be around 3.5V (1mA 3.5k)  vs 5V. 5V would be a little better as it scales the output up.

Comment: The datasheet of the sensor says the sensitivity will be in mV(mA x bar). I think I am going to use another IC for a constant current source. That way I can also put a thermocouple on the ADC and have it all under one I2C location.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help though. Really cleared it up for me!